# C# console application exe file does not start

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have created a console application project at .NET framework 4.0 (I tried to change it several times). In order to have abilities to print images via this app, I have added a reference for the System.Drawing assembly. When I run that app in VS - it works fine, but once I run the exe file - it always shows in processes but does not do anything, moreover I cannot finish it's process.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing.Printing;


namespace printCA
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

                string filePath;
                if (args.Length > 1)
                    filePath = args[1];
                else
                    filePath ="D:\\image.jpg";



            PrintDocument p = new PrintDocument();
            p.PrintPage += delegate (object sender1, PrintPageEventArgs e1)
            {
                System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(filePath);
                System.Drawing.Point loc = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
                e1.Graphics.DrawImage(img, loc);


            };
            try
            {
                p.Print();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Exception Occured While Printing", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried attaching the debugger to the running process?  You may be able to get some information from there.

Also check your event logs to check for possible printer issues.

Comment: Are you running the exe on the same computer as your visual studio installation?

Comment: Yes,I running the exe on the same computer

Comment: I didn't try to attach debugger, but I looked at windows events logger and no errors where there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I had disabled an antivirus the app started to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your EXE is exiting before your delegate has fired.  You should insert some diagnostics and try putting this at the end to stop the process exiting:

```
Console.WriteLine("Press RETURN> ");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I have already ran the code that consisted only you suggested lines and nothing more , but the behavior was same - app didn't do anything, only process was shown . I think It can be some issue of  creating exe with external dependencies but i didn't find out what exactly

Comment: What if you open a command prompt and run the EXE from there?

Comment: It sounds very odd.  I wonder if your EXE has been fingered by an anti-virus program?  
I would be inclined to reboot, start a whole new console project with a different name "Test1", just write out some console text and see what happens.

Comment: Phil, thanks! It was an antivirus who blocked app. It's strange that it didn't show any warning concerning app I ran